# MYSQL - Set Sequence of users

Tags: mysql

I want to set display sequence for all users

i have taken select box for set sequence

where i have displayed total no of users like now total records are 5 then i will display

```
1,2,3,4,5

id  name    sequence
------------------------
1   Steve   3
2   lee     2
3   Lisa    1
4   John    0
5   smith   0
```

But when i am going to edit tab sequence for John i want to display 4 OR 5 in select box

because 1,2,3 are already used for other users

Can i manage all things in single query

Please advice

Comment: So is it about putting numbers in consecutive order?

Comment: Want to display those number that are not used previously..

Comment: Should that be `MAX(sequence) + 1`? Or what should that be if you have `1,2,4` used - `3` or `5` ?

Comment: If we used 1.2,4 for any of users then we have available sequences are 3 & 5...